# TypeError: an integer is required (got type str) mixer

Tags: python, pygame, mixer

So im making a python game with python and I'm using mixer to play audio, but when I run the game this error shows

```
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.16, Python 3.8.12)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
music started playing....
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 22, in <module>
    mixer.music.play('walk the dinosaur.mp3')
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)"
```

this is my code

```
import pyflakes
import pygame
import os
from pygame import mixer

pygame.init()

loc = 1
input 
wtd = 'walk the dinosaur.mp3'
mixer.init()

#Load audio file
mixer.music.load('walk the dinosaur.mp3')

print("music started playing....")

#Set preferred volume
mixer.music.set_volume(0.2)

#Play the music
mixer.music.play('walk the dinosaur.mp3')
```

Comment: Docs are always the best place to start: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.play.

`play` does not take the name of a file as input.

Answer (score 1):

According to pygame's documentation (https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.play),
the `play` function doesn't have any required parameters. Unless you want to change any of the default ones (loops, start, or fade_ms) you don't need to pass anything to it.

Answer (score 1):

Play only starts the preloaded track, what you are searching for is

```
mixer.music.load('walk the dinosaur.mp3')
mixer.music.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to give the name of the file again in the `play` function. Also play is async, so you will need to wait before exiting.

```
import pyflakes
import pygame
import os
from pygame import mixer

pygame.init()
mixer.init()

#Load audio file
mixer.music.load('walk the dinosaur.mp3')

print("music started playing....")

#Set preferred volume
mixer.music.set_volume(0.2)

#Play the music
mixer.music.play()
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy(): 
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)
```